# .Net Undefined Object Type

Tags: c#, .net, oop

There must be a property of unknown type in my model, because I need to define which class this property should be after I produce the model, according to the string data I retrieved from the database. I do this, but I can't access the methods in it because I defined the object later and it doesn't have a static type. What should I do about this issue and what is the most effective solution?

My .Net Freamwork Windows Service

```
foreach (var item in devices)
{
    Thread th = new Thread(item.Driver.Start); // in this block i cant go to Start method in the driver
}
```

My .Net Core Worker Service

```
foreach (var item in devices)
{
    Thread th = new Thread(item.Driver.Start); // in this block i cant go to Start method in the driver
}
```

As you can see the two projects are exactly the same. When I develop windows service using .net framework, threads run very fast. But the threads of .net core and worker services do not work at the same performance.

Not: My Driver class using Some TCP requests and mysql records.

Comment: @JonasH can u look at this problem

Comment: Could you please describe the problem in more detail? It is not clear from your question what is wrong with the current code or what your desired outcome is. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: It looks like you are trying to call `Start()` on a property of type `object`, but since you didn't provide a [mre] I can't really tell.

Comment: See [How can I mention/tag any user in a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97471/how-can-i-mention-tag-any-user-in-a-post). But it is not clear to me what the actual goal is.

Comment: `Device.Driver` is a property of type `object` so `item.Driver.Start` will fail since [`Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object?view=net-6.0) does not define a `Start` member.

Comment: @DavidG : You do not understand the hardware interfaces.  There is a hardware block and Microsoft GENERIC Drivers do not are not always capable of reading all vendors hardware blocks.  There are optional parameters that vendors implement that are not compatible with the generic drivers.

Comment: @jdweng It seems I understand far more than you though. Your comment, even if it were true, is completely irrelevant to the question being asked.

Comment: @DavidG : You would get the error is the driver installed did not match the Modbus hardware being used.  This error often occurs when the GENERIC Microsoft driver does not work with the manufacturers hardware.

Comment: @jdweng No it isn't though! The error is trying to call a method on a `object` instead of the actual type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what abstraction is all about my friend. You should create an Interface for example `IDriver` and then you can create multiple classes which will inherits from this interface. In the interface you can declare methods which inheriting class HAVE TO implement. Then you can simply change your Driver field type from `object` to `IDriver`. To be honest your problem is a common thing in programming in general and you can look up for Design Patterns - it will help you alot believe me. I am an automation engineer and i know what you are trying to achieve. What will you do when your Device will have to be compatible with Profibus instead of Modbus? What about CANopen and EtherCAT?

Remember to keep your Interfaces as small as possible. Don't build interfaces where you'll have to implement methods that fits only to one type of object. For example, you don't want to create `IPrinter` because there are also printers integrated with scanners and if `IPrinter` have to implement methods for printing and scanning thats bad becouse that forces all printers to implement methos for scanning. Instead of that you should create `IPrinter` and `IScanner` as separate interfaces even if these will have only one method. Then you can inherit from `IPrinter` in classes that represents printers without scanners and in those with scanners you can simpli inherits from both interfaces! Siple as that!

Design Patterns and SOLID are your good friends and these will save alot of your time.

Keep it up! I went through that and i fcked up my SCADA exactly the same way because of my lack of knowledge.

Feel free to ask me anything :)

Comment: Ahh thanks man, i think i need interfaces but i wondred is there an another solve for this problem. i see most effiency is interfaces. ill rebuild now. are u working on scada systems ?

Comment: I've built my own which i've never released to the world. There are other ways to solve the problem, another approach is to use abstract classes but that approach is worse because it limits higer level classes as you would use one common interface for all objects. Aaaaand there is one more, but i do not reccoment that approach. In .NET exist a type called dynamic. dynamic driver = new ExpandoObject(). This way you can use this  object in JavaScript-like way. But forget about data consistency, spelling checks which intellisense provide and it wil likely lead you to mindblow some day trust me xD

Comment: Check it out if you want: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCKmhf6pYA96E45nB6cImuJQ

Comment: If you don't already have static typing, it will probably be confusing in the future. so I will create a driver interface and sample my driver from here, so I can run every driver with a common class, thank you very much for your information.
 :)